# AWS federated login name

Tags: amazon-web-services, federated-identity, federated

1) I was successfully able to create a federated login using ADFS, Shibboleth, cognito and Auth0. In all the identity providers I used the login name shows the IAM role/ Username like the following screenshot

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UntU.png)

While the aim is to show only the username like the following screenshots:

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WkVe.png)

how can I managed to remove the IAM role so it shows only the username like the 2nd screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

AWS uses RoleSessionName attribute for the username shown. so in your samlResponse you can send this attribute and AWS service provider will pick it up.

you can check the list of attributes used by AWS in their saml metadata file :  https://signin.aws.amazon.com/static/saml-metadata.xml